# Hashtable how to get string value without toString()

Tags: c#, class, hashtable, overriding, tostring

How could I get the string value from a hashtable without calling toString() methode?

example: my class:

```
public class myHashT : Hashtable
{
 public myHashT () { }
 ...
 public override object this[object key]
      {
         get
         {
            return base[key].ToString(); <--this doesn't work!
         }
         set
         {
            base[key] = value;
         }
      } 
}
```

In an other class:

```
myHashT hT;
string test = hT["someKey"];
```

it works with `hT["someKey"].toString();` but I need it without calling `ToString()` and without casting to (string).

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?  Compile error?  If you are returning an object, why do you need ToString()?  base[key] will give you an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use System.Collections.Generic.HashSet. Alternately use composition instead of inheritance ie. have hashtable be your private field and write your own indexer that does ToString().

```
public class myHashT
{
public myHashT () { }
...

private Hashtable _ht;

public string this[object key]
{
  get
  {
     return _ht[key].ToString();
  }
  set
  {
     _ht[key] = value;
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Can you just cast?

```
(string)hT["someKey"]
```

Note that if this is 2.0 or above, a generic `Dictionary<string,string>` would be far simpler... and in 1.1 `StringDictionary` would do the job (although IIRC you need to watch for case-insensitivity in the key).

Comment: It'll be about the same; O(1)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, value in the hashtable is a string?

If so, you need to cast the object as a String.

```
string test = (string)hT["someKey"];
```